# meaning of "the rather," "than," respectively

Tags: grammar

> This may be fancy, though I think the memory of most of us can go
>   farther back into such times than many of us suppose; just as I
>   believe the power of observation in numbers of very young children to
>   be quite wonderful for its closeness and accuracy. Indeed, I think
>   that most grown men who are remarkable in this respect, may with
>   greater propriety be said not to have lost the faculty, **than** to have
>   acquired it; **the rather**, as I generally observe such men to retain a
>   certain freshness, and gentleness, and capacity of being pleased,
>   which are also an inheritance they have preserved from their
>   childhood. (Charles Dickens, *David Copperfield*, CHAPTER 2. I
>   OBSERVE)

Does *than* in this excerpt mean *but* = *be said not to have lost the faculty, but to have acquired it*?

Does *the rather* in this fragment mean *the latter* = *the latter* (e.g. the faculty having been acquired), *as I generally observe...*?

I should finally say that I actually don't know what *the rather* means. I haven't been able to find it in any of the free online English dictionaries that I've looked it up in. I'm very sure *the rather* is included in *OED*, but this is a lexicographic work that is without my reach.

Comment: Archaic syntax. Not surprising from something that old.

Comment: Depends on whether the reader wants to stop and smell the syntax. Not everyone enjoys distraction from the story.

Comment: _... the roar of the crowd_ is considerably louder than the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, I think that most grown men who are remarkable in this respect, may more accurately be said not to have lost the faculty, **rather than** to have acquired it. **This seems all the more likely to me**, as I generally observe that such men retain a certain freshness, and gentleness, and capacity to be pleased: other characteristics they have possessed from childhood.

And I'd stop using 'without' for 'beyond' or 'outside' if you want to sound normal.

Comment: 'All the more so' in general.

Comment: @Patrick: You might also wish to note that although it makes no real difference to the overall sense of the passage, replacing **than** with **but** would actually change the *structure*. That's because **than** links back to *with greater propriety than that*, whereas **but** links back to *not to have lost, but to have acquired*.